# Python - Vincenty's inverse formula not converging (Finding distance between points on Earth)

Tags: python, math, formula, wiki

I'm attempting to implement Vincenty's inverse problem as described on wiki [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae#Inverse_problem)

The problem is that lambda is simply not converging. The value stays the same if I try to iterate over the sequence of formulas, and I'm really not sure why. Perhaps I've just stared myself blind on an obvious problem.

It should be noted that I'm new to Python and still learning the language, so I'm not sure if it's misuse of the language that might cause the problem, or if I do have some mistakes in some of the calculations that I perform. I just can't seem to find any mistakes in the formulas.

Basically, I've written in the code in as close of a format as I could to the wiki article, and the result is this:

```
import math

# Length of radius at equator of the ellipsoid
a = 6378137.0

# Flattening of the ellipsoid
f = 1/298.257223563

# Length of radius at the poles of the ellipsoid
b = (1 - f) * a

# Latitude points
la1, la2 = 10, 60

# Longitude points
lo1, lo2 = 5, 150

# For the inverse problem, we calculate U1, U2 and L.
# We set the initial value of lamb = L
u1 = math.atan( (1 - f) * math.tan(la1) )
u2 = math.atan( (1 - f) * math.tan(la2) )
L = (lo2 - lo1) * 0.0174532925

lamb = L

while True:
    sinArc = math.sqrt( math.pow(math.cos(u2) * math.sin(lamb),2) + math.pow(math.cos(u1) * math.sin(u2) - math.sin(u1) * math.cos(u2) * math.cos(lamb),2) )
    cosArc = math.sin(u1) * math.sin(u2) + math.cos(u1) * math.cos(u2) * math.cos(lamb)
    arc = math.atan2(sinArc, cosArc)
    sinAzimuth = ( math.cos(u1) * math.cos(u2) * math.sin(lamb) ) // ( sinArc )
    cosAzimuthSqr = 1 - math.pow(sinAzimuth, 2)
    cosProduct = cosArc - ((2 * math.sin(u1) * math.sin(u2) ) // (cosAzimuthSqr))
    C = (f//16) * cosAzimuthSqr  * (4 + f * (4 - 3 * cosAzimuthSqr))
    lamb = L + (1 - C) * f * sinAzimuth * ( arc + C * sinArc * ( cosProduct + C * cosArc * (-1 + 2 * math.pow(cosProduct, 2))))
    print(lamb)
```

As mentioned the problem is that the value "lamb" (lambda) will not become smaller. I've even tried to compare my code to other implementations, but they looked just about the same.

What am I doing wrong here? :-)

Thank you all!

Comment: In your example, which value should `lamb` converge to?

Comment: Try `from __future__ import division`

Comment: First off, perhaps you should get rid of integer divisions (`//`) and replace them by float divisions (`/`)?

Comment: Then, I think there's a misunderstanding in the mathematical writing you read on the page you linked to. When they say `sin α = blabla`, it doesn't mean `sinAlpha = blabla`, but it means `α = arcsin blablabla`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not put that change in the code :-) lamb should converge towards the mentioned value in the wiki article, that is: "When λ has converged to the desired degree of accuracy (10^(−12) corresponds to approximately 0.06mm)". So, I'm trying to get it to converge towards that value

Comment: In that case, I've clearly misunderstood the mathematical writing!

Comment: Well, wait. What I've said is true, but in fact it doesn't matter since you don't want `α` directly. So it seems ok for this part.

Comment: @Bitious in `L = (lo2 - lo1) * 0.0174532925`, why `* 0.017...`? The wiki article doesn't mention this.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the help so far jivan! :) It is wonderful! I multiplied by 0.017... in order to convert the lo2, lo1 values from degrees to radian, however I'm not sure if this is needed. It was based on another example I found on the internet.

Comment: @Bitious it's ok, I made an explanation in the comments of my answer - I refer you to that

Comment: When calculating `u1` and `u2`, shouldn't you be converting `la1` and `la2` to radians before calling `math.tan()`?

Comment: @JimLewis this is the goal of `L = (lo2 - lo1) * 0.0174532925` - `0.017...` equals `math.pi / 180`

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about la1 and la2 in the immediately preceding lines.

Comment: @JimLewis - you're absolutely right

Comment: I think you might be correct @JimLewis, they should be converted to radians the same way I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should convert you latitudes in radians too (you already do this for your longitudes):

```
u1 = math.atan( (1 - f) * math.tan(math.radians(la1)) )
u2 = math.atan( (1 - f) * math.tan(math.radians(la2)) )
L = math.radians((lo2 - lo1)) # better than * 0.0174532925
```

Once you do this and get rid of `//` (`int` divisions) and replace them by `/` (`float` divisions), `lambda` stops repeating the same value through your iterations and starts following this path (based on your example coordinates):

```
2.5325205864224847
2.5325167509030906
2.532516759118641
2.532516759101044
2.5325167591010813
2.5325167591010813
2.5325167591010813
```

As you seem to expect a convergence precision of `10^(−12)`, it seems to make the point.

You can now exit the loop (`lambda` having converged) and keep going until you compute the desired geodesic distance `s`.

Note: [you can test your final value `s` here](http://planetcalc.com/73/).

Comment: yes it's actually correct - except you're not done yet. Lambda is not the distance between two points but an angle. This result (2.5343...) seems correct. You now need to go on (out of the loop) with the second part until you compute `s` which is the geodesic distance, which is what you want in the end.

Comment: Thank you Jivan! :-) Yes, I'm aware that I still need to implement the second part, however I wanted to make sure the first step of the process was correct first :) Thank you a lot for the help!

Comment: @Bitious: FWIW, the `math` module provides `degrees()` and `radians()` functions to convert radians to degrees and vice versa. Using these functions instead of multiplying or dividing by pi/180 or obscure [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) like 0.0174532925 makes code more readable.

Comment: Cheers @PM2Ring ! :) I'll use these functions instead!

Answer (score 3):

Even if it is correctly implemented, Vincenty's algorithm will fail to
converge for some points.  (This problem was noted by Vincenty.)
I give an algorithm which is guaranteed to
converge in [*Algorithms for geodesics*](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z); there's a python
implementation available [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/geographiclib).  Finally, you can find more
information on the problem at the Wikipedia page,
[*Geodesics on an ellipsoid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid).  (The talk page has examples
of pairs of points for which Vincenty, as implemented by the NGS,
fails to converge.)

Comment: I've submitted a [patch](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/pull/144) to [geopy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy) to use the accurate geographiclib algorithms if they are available.